# Obtain exact bounding box coordinates for ggplot2 texts

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, geom

I want to know the coordinates for the bounding box (top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right coordinates) for the text "ABC" as shown in the screenshot:

[image: example]

My code is:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 0, text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, label = text)) + geom_text()
```

In this example, the coordinate of the bottom of the text (this is what I am looking for) is: x = 0.0125, y = 0.002 .

I appreciate any solution/suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: In what units and relative to what? In cm, parental coordinates, inches, points, data units? Relative to the panel, the plot area?

Comment: In terms of the coordinates. I just revised the questions. If there is way to get cm/inches/points, that will be better.